# I am creating struts 2 application and creating in jboss server when i deploy i am receiving following error

Tags: jboss, struts2

error due to the following reason(s): org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'type'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":rtexprvalue, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":deferred-value, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":deferred-method, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":fragment}' is expected. @ vfs:///D:/MyWorkSpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1320131485912/deploy/JbossPOC.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl.jar/META-INF/html_basic.tld[1625,19]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with Struts2, After looking at the output content it seems that content are not as per the XSD and validation error is being thrown by the system.

There seems some issue with the tld.